# Spring boot thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

im using spring boot 2.6.3 and i tried to use thymeleaf recently to get a confirmation message with html after i confirm my account via mail (im just using confirmation mail to verify the new accounts) so i watched some videos about thymeleaf and i marked that all the videos have a folder named templates and static in the src/main/ressources and i dont have them o so i created a folder named templates and in the folder i created a html file just to try it if it (the html file contains simple message hello world) so like you can see in the screenshots i got my controller done and it returns the name of the html file .. i dont know why i keep receiving it as simple string message ``
here is the screenshots
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9JGY.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JxjI.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkLgO.png

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I do see that already you have a get-mapping for /email-verification, so can you use different name for this thymeleaf file here.

Make sure you're using same name for URL path and template file.

Comment: yes i tried it with a different name (new html file name) but its still the same it gets back a simple message